# Resize bitmap with API level 14, in android

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

In android:
My min target API level is 14 and I try to resize a bitmap that I read from file. When I use reconfigure() or setwidth() or setHight(), the application fail and tell that these functions for API 19 and the current  min API is 14.
I didn't want to change min API target. How may I resize the bitmap??

Reminder: my bitmap is full of data from file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap` to create a new, scaled bitmap.